# Robust Regression

Tags: regression, robust, mad

The Median Absolute Deviation (MAD) is often used as a measure of dispersion of the residuals in robust regression.  For univariate data, MAD is computed by first finding the median of the data, then finding the absolute deviations of each value from the median, and then finding the median of these absolute deviations.

For regression residuals, some sources describe computation of MAD in exactly the same way as for univariate data. Other sources state that the residuals MAD is simply the median of the absolute values of the residuals.  Which is correct?

Comment: How do the measures differ? Do they differ? Aren't they the same thing? A residual is, by definition, a deviation, isn't it?

Comment: Hello DJohnson, thanks for your response.  I agree with your point that the residual is a deviation so if we use the first approach, we would be finding the deviation of a deviation. But the two approaches aren't the same. For instance I have the following 7 residuals: -.29, .25, .24, .16, .09, -.27, -.43. The median is .09 and the median of the absolute deviations from .09 is .16. But if I simply find the median of the absolute values of the residuals, that value is .25.  So is MAD .16 or .25? Thanks, Ike

Comment: Based on your report, the literature supports both approaches. This means that there is no generally accepted or agreed upon answer to your question. Take your pick, just be prepared to justify the decision.

Comment: If an appropriate measure of centrality of the residuals is not zero, then the model probably has not been correctly fit--equivalently, the nonzero amount can be incorporated in an intercept term.  Thus, practically by definition, all that matters when assessing the spread of residuals is their deviations from zero: that is, their absolute values.